# Python, serial - changing baudrate, strange behaviour

Tags: python, pyserial

I am having troubles with changing baudrate while the port is running. All the communication is run at 100k baud, but I also need to send some data at 10k baud. I've read I should use setBaudrate method, so I tried this:

```
ser = serial.Serial(2, baudrate=BAUD, timeout=TIMEOUT)

def reset(string):
    if string:
        ser.flushInput() #erase input and output buffers
        ser.flushOutput()
        ser.setBaudrate(RESET_BAUD) #change baudrate to 10k
        ser.write(string)
        ser.setBaudrate(BAUD) #go back to 100k
```

The problem is, it doesn't work right. I don't know what is wrong here, but the string just isn't received properly. But here is interesting part - if I remove the last line (going back to 100k) and run this function from the shell, everything is fine. Then I can just run the last command directly in shell, not inside function.

My question is what exactly happens here and how to avoid it? All I need is a function to send a string with different baudrate and then return to the original baudrate...

Comment: I can't find the `setBaudrate` method in the documentation. Maybe it is deprecated? Also, maybe did you try flushing the output buffer **after** setting the baudrate the second time?

Comment: When you remove that last line (go back to 100kBaud), can you send a good number of commands at that 10kBaud setting? Are these all properly received?

Comment: I've tried many combinations, the situation wasn't clear to me so I did some experiments there :D. Receiver got every string sent without the last line.

Anyway problem is solved, I need to manually wait until the write buffer is empty. Thanks for your time!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to wait long enough for the string to be sent before resetting the BAUD rate - otherwise it changes while some of it is still in the serial port *(hardware)* buffer.

Add `time.sleep(0.01*len(string))` before the last line.

BTW try not to use reserved words like `string` as variable names as it can cause problems.

Comment: Isn't flushing the buffer a better way to do this?

Comment: @RafaelLerm - In practice not reliably because flush empties the OS buffers then returns allowing the hardware change rate to get to the chip before the hardware buffers have been emptied in the RS232 UART.  In many chipsets the speed change will then take place immediately despite the fact that there are a number of bytes/bits in transit through the chip.

Answer (score 2):

My guess is that the baud rate is being changed before the data is actually sent. A good bet is to force the data to be sent before trying to change the baud rate.

According to the [docs](http://pyserial.sourceforge.net/pyserial_api.html#serial.Serial.flush), this is done by calling `Serial.flush()` (not `flushInput()` or `flushOutput()`, as these just discard the buffer contents).

Comment: I'm not sure why, but flush() doesn't seem to work properly. No difference between flush() and no delay...